# CSS to force inline input fields

Tags: html, css

I have the following code and I am unable to access the HTML to edit.

```
<form>
   <div class="LoginDiv">
      <input type="text" name="user_login" tabindex="1" placeholder="Email"/>
   </div>
   <div class="LoginDiv">
      <input type="password" name="user_password" tabindex="2" placeholder="Password" />
   </div>
   <button type="submit">LOGIN</button>
</form>
```

This displays as per the image.

[image]

I am able to access the CSS and I would like to be able to force the input fields so they are inline.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

John

Comment: what exactly you want to happen? inputs and button are inline? in one straight line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you need I guess

```
.LoginDiv {
  display: inline-block;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/21o0uL52/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float:left` on input and added button in div with `class submit`. By using `clear:both` avoided to `float`

```css
form input{
 float:left;
}
.submit{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<form>
   <div class="LoginDiv">
      <input type="text" name="user_login" tabindex="1" placeholder="Email"/>
   </div>
   <div class="LoginDiv">
      <input type="password" name="user_password" tabindex="2" placeholder="Password" />
   </div>
   <div class="submit"><button type="submit">LOGIN</button></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only must use display: inline. EDITED

```css
div{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<form>
   <div class="LoginDiv">
      <input type="text" name="user_login" tabindex="1" placeholder="Email"/>
   </div>
   <div class="LoginDiv">
      <input type="password" name="user_password" tabindex="2" placeholder="Password" />
   </div>
   <button type="submit">LOGIN</button>
</form>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/a080er0g/2/)

Comment: The OP has mentioned that he does not have access to edit the html

Comment: Good observation! Edited

Comment: It would bad to make the `div` inline. They can be other divs on the page and they might get `inline`d too, breaking the page

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `float: left` to the class of these `div`'s, something like this:

```css
.LoginDiv {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="LoginDiv">
    <input type="text" name="user_login" tabindex="1" placeholder="Email" />
  </div>
  <div class="LoginDiv">
    <input type="password" name="user_password" tabindex="2" placeholder="Password" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit">LOGIN</button>
</form>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/46L1jdkr/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline table and table cell.

```
display:inline-table;
```

See fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/mLjh8230/